# Compile and install from sources a modified version of a program.

Tags: compilation

I have installed certain program from sources (using ./configure, make, make install). I'd like to compile it again, after modifying the sources, just for testing the changes. But I want the new version to be installed separately, with another name, so that I can still use the previous version of the program. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did what I needed, but in another way than I pretended at the beggining (much easier).
What I did was to simply compile it entirely with g++ compiler (the program was written in c++).